# How Jquery datatable read serverside datatable which is converted to Json format using aspx web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, datatables-1.10

I am new to Jquery and trying to add custom search with a text box and check box using Jquery Datatables [[link]][1]. Here my first approach was to read server-side data table converted to JSON using Jquery Ajax but I am not sure How to get this working. There is no much explanation about aspx web method. 
my code is :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{

    string jstring = string.Empty;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("pname");
    dt.Columns.Add("loc");
    dt.Columns.Add("country");
    dt.Columns.Add("fname");
    dt.Rows.Add("abcd", "xxx", "ie", "NIKE");
    dt.Rows.Add("kbfdgh", "blackrock", "uk", "Didi");
    dt.Rows.Add("gtrjht", "malahide", "uk", "OPEN");
    dt.Rows.Add("wxznay", "CORK", "ie", "WIN");
    return jstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}

}
```

.aspx code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": false,
            "serverSide": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "Default.aspx/GetData",
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                    return $.parseJSON(json.d);
                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to show the JSON data table from server side into jquery data table. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Your first problem is this: `"serverSide": false,`

Comment: Hi masrkpsmith , I have changed the code :  "processing": true, "serverSide": true,   it gives me an  error: 1. Warning: Invalid JSON response

Comment: So have a look at the JSON response - find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: The #2 error is caused by `$.parseJSON(json.d)` there is no need for that, the reponse is already in JSON format - just `return json.d` ...

Comment: Can you please show your JSON response?

Comment: Hi All ,  I was not getting proper JSON response . Finally ,its working now and will update my code . It will help somebody

Comment: There is a good tutorial on jquery data tables  server side processing  by kudvenkat --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgD24a9gxXw&index=106&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap